# how to join two multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how to join two multidimensional arrays in php? I have two multidimensional arrays A and B. I need to join A and B to form a new array C as follows

```
$A = array( 
array("a1"=>1,"b1"=>2,"c1"=>"A"), 
array("a1"=>1,"b1"=>16,"c1"=>"Z"), 
array("a1"=>3,"b1"=>8,"c1"=>"A")); 

$B = array( 
array("a2"=>1,"b2"=>2,"b2"=>"A"), 
array("a2"=>1,"b2"=>16,"b2"=>"G"), 
array("a2"=>3,"b2"=>8,"b2"=>"A"));
```

//join A and B to form C

```
$C=array( 
array("a1"=>1,"b1"=>2,"c1"=>"A"), 
array("a1"=>1,"b1"=>16,"c1"=>"Z"), 
array("a1"=>3,"b1"=>8,"c1"=>"A"),
array("a2"=>1,"b2"=>2,"b2"=>"A"), 
array("a2"=>1,"b2"=>16,"b2"=>"G"), 
array("a2"=>3,"b2"=>8,"b2"=>"A"));
```

Comment: Do you want to keep both data or pick the unique values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `array_merge` function, like this:

```
$C = array_merge($A, $B);
print_r($C);
```

When I run the above script it'll output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [a1] => 1 
        [b1] => 2 
        [c1] => A 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [a1] => 1 
        [b1] => 16 
        [c1] => Z
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [a1] => 3 
        [b1] => 8 
        [c1] => A 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [a2] => 1 
        [b2] => A
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [a2] => 1 
        [b2] => G 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [a2] => 3 
        [b2] => A 
    )
)
```

Take a quick read here: http://php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 4):

```
$C = array_merge($A, $B);
```

should do the trick ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)).

Answer (score 3):

Did you try some PHP array functions? I think some of these work: [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-merge-recursive.php), [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php).

```
$array1 = array("farbe" => "rot", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "farbe" => "grün", "form" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do this as

```
foreach($B as $key => $value){
    $C[$key] = array_merge($A[$key], $B[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I have faced same situation where i had to show duplicate events in calendar

So i used this solution:-

```
 public function array_interlace() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $total = count($args);

    if($total < 2) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $arr = array();

    foreach($args as $arg) {
        foreach($arg as $v) {
            $arr[$j] = $v;
            $j += $total;
        }

        $i++;
        $j = $i;
    }

    ksort($arr);
    return array_values($arr);
}
```

Required output of array

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$b = array('a','e', 'f', 'g');
$c = array('h', 'i', 'j');
$d = array('k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o');

print_r(array_interlace($a, $b, $c, $d));
Array
(
[0] => a
[1] => a
[2] => h
[3] => k
[4] => b
[5] => e
[6] => i
[7] => l
[8] => c
[9] => f
[10] => j
[11] => m
[12] => d
[13] => g
[14] => n
[15] => o
)
```

I found this solution suitable..