# Joining two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays each coming from different DB queries, I can't join them in DB so I have to join them using php.
The first:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 2
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 1
            [status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 2
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

And I wanna join it with this array on `pos_id` and `id`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Front
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Back
        )
)
```

so that, the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 2
            [name] => Back
            [status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 1
            [name] => Front

            [status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [host_id] => 5
            [pos_id] => 2
            [name] => Back
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

The code I have uses an inner loop, matches the value and pushes into array:

```
foreach($events as &$event) {
    foreach($positions as $position) {
        if($player[pos_id] == $position[id]){
            array_push($event,"name",$position[name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have some code? Or just waiting for us to write you code for free?

Comment: I don't need someone to write me a code, I can easily make a code using a loop with inner loop to match and join both. I'm just wondering if there's a better way that I am missing with a lower time complexity.

Comment: Btw, how is `pos_id = 0` connected with `id = 1`?

Comment: Sorry that was a dummy code, fixed it to match id

Comment: (quote:) 'I can easily make a code using a loop with inner loop' -- rewrite second array as an associative array first (`[ '1' => 'Front', '2' => 'Back' ]`), then loop over the first array and add the appropriate names. Saves you an inner loop, resulting in `N + M` operations instead of `N * M`

Comment: Show how you fetch the rows, that's where you should do it.

Comment: I have added my sample code

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109815/how-to-join-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Comment: @PetervanderWal while this has a better complexity, it would require that I firstly loop the second array to covert it into associative array and then join the arrays.

Comment: @ahmed.soli I believe that the question addresses merging two arrays rather than joining.

Comment: Yes, that's my point indeed. But your second foreach will be a much cleaner and faster one than the one you have now: `foreach($events as &$event) { $event['name'] = $positions[ $event['pos_id'] ]; }`

Comment: You can loop over the first array using for loop and inside the loop make the validation using the two arrays if value of the post id of the first equal to value if id of the second then add the name to the first array i can write the code if you want

Comment: @ahmed.soli thank you, that's pretty much the sample code I have written, I will go with Peter's suggestion using associative array.