# How can I merge array in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

How can I merge array in multidimensional array . I'm very confuse

I've 2 array

```
$getLate = [
  0 => {
    "id": 1
    "name": "student1"
    "totalLate": 1
  }
  1 => {
    "id": 3
    "name": "student2"
    "totalLate": 1
  }
]


$getName = [ 
0 => {
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "student1"
  }
  1 => {
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "student2"
  }
  2 => {
    +"id": 4
    +"name": "student3"
  }
```

and I want to check :

`if $getName['name'] = $getLate['name']` I want to add totalLate  into `$getName`;

How can I merge them so that the output looks like this

```
$getLate = [
  0 => {
    "id": 1
    "name": "student1"
    "totalLate": 1
  }
  1 => {
    "id": 3
    "name": "student2"
    "totalLate": 1
  }
  2 => {
    +"id": 4
    +"name": "student3"
    "totalLate": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to join two multidimensional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109815/how-to-join-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($getLate as $key => $value){
    $output[] = (object)array_merge((array)$getName[$key], (array)$value);
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: it's output only 2 array  same as $getLate

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.