# How to combine two different multi dimensional arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to combine two different multi-dimensional arrays, with one providing the correct structure (keys) and the other one the data to fill it (values).

Notice that I can't control how the arrays are formed, the structure might vary in different situations.

```
$structure = [
    "a",
    "b" => [
        "b1",
        "b2" => [
            "b21",
            "b22"
        ]
    ]
];

$data = [A, B1, B21, B22];
```

Expected result:

```
$array = [
    "a" => "A",
    "b" => [
        "b1" => "B1",
        "b2" => [
            "b21" => "B21",
            "b22" => "B22"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: What are the criteria? Should the values be set in order or should the lower-cased keys match upper-cased values?

Comment: They should match by their place. The first element of $data should combine with the first key without element of $structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, however it will only work if number of elements in `$data` is same or more than `$structure`.

```
$filled = 0;
array_walk_recursive ($structure, function (&$val)  use (&$filled, $data) {
    $val = array( $val => $data[ $filled ] ); 
    $filled++; 
});

print_r( $structure );
```

Here is a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/kitiP)

Answer (score 1):

You can try by a recursive way. Write a recursive method which takes an array as first argument to alter and the data set as its second argument. This method itself call when any array element is another array, else it alters the key and value with the help of data set.

```
$structure = [
    "a",
    "b" => [
        "b1",
        "b2" => [
            "b21",
            "b22"
        ]
    ]
];

$data = ['A', 'B1', 'B21', 'B22'];


function alterKey(&$arr, $data) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (!is_array($val)) {
            $data_key = array_search(strtoupper($val), $data);
            $arr[$val] = $data[$data_key];
            unset($arr[$key]);
        } else {
            $arr[$key] = alterKey($val, $data);
        }
    }

    ksort($arr);
    return $arr;
}

alterKey($structure, $data);

echo '<pre>', print_r($structure);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/IQ7vA).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   $structure = [
    "a",
    "b" => [
    "b1",
    "b2" => [
        "b21",
        "b22"
            ]
      ]
];

$new_structure = array();
foreach($structure as $key =>$value)
{
  if(!is_array($value))
    {
      $new_structure[$value]= $value;
    }else{
      foreach($value as $k =>$v)
        {
          if(!is_array($v))
           { 
              $new_structure[$key][$v]=$v; 
           }else
           {
             foreach($v as $kk => $vv)
             {
                   $new_structure[$k][$vv]=$vv;                                   
             }            
           }
        }
     }
}
print_r($new_structure);exit;
```

Comment: Where have you used $data?

Answer (score -1):

Use 
$array=array_merge($structure,$data);
for more information follow this link
[how to join two multidimensional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109815/how-to-join-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)